# prevent bootstrap collapse to re-animate when clicking an item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a sidebar implemented using bootstrap collapsible,
The menus are all in  tagged my issue is when i clicked on this tagged,
the page refreshed thus re-animating the collapsible panel and it doesnt look good

I have already stored the stage of this collapsible items in a cookie to know the previous state before reloading but now its the reanimation of it collapsing is what is happening.

How to solve this?

```
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ui-basic" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="ui-basic">
                <i class="icon-layout menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Listing Management</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="ui-basic">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu sideBarPanel">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL">Create</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL})">Featured List</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL"})">Automated List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ui-basic" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="ui-basic">
                <i class="icon-layout menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Listing Management</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="ui-basic">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu sideBarPanel">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL">Option 4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL})">Option 5</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL"})">Option 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easy to understand, so please rephrase it if this is not the answer you were looking for.

Looking at your code though, you are duplicating IDs and both `.nav-links`s have the same `data-bs-target` target. So that won't work.

Make each toggle target and collapse ID unique:

```
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ui-basic" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="ui-basic">
                <i class="icon-layout menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Listing Management</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="ui-basic">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu sideBarPanel">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL">Create</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL})">Featured List</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL"})">Automated List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ui-basic-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="ui-basic-2">
                <i class="icon-layout menu-icon"></i>
                <span class="menu-title">Listing Management</span>
                <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="ui-basic-2">
                <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu sideBarPanel">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL">Option 4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL})">Option 5</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/someURL"})">Option 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```